# Devise is added to user,Existing first name last name doesn't appear even after over riding the configure_permitted_parameters action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am working on a rails application  created user model with first name last name and added devise. when i added those existing fields in the  registration form it is not shown in the page. i have overridden configure_permitted_parameters method in application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protected
    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
    end
end


<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <%= f.input :first_name,
                 required: true,
                 autofocus: true,
                 input_html: { autocomplete: "first_name" }%>
    <%= f.input :last_name,
                 required: true,
                 autofocus: true,
                 input_html: { autocomplete: "last_name" }%>

    <%= f.input :email,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "email" }%>
    <%= f.input :password,
                required: true,
                hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length),
                input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation,
                required: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise is still using it's default views I bet. You have to update your routes file to use your views for Devise.

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "users/registrations"}
```

Where `:users` is the model name and `"users/registrations"` is the path.  so if your model is different, or path is different for whatever reason, then update that path to the view files.

Comment: i was missing controllers in your suggested line of code thanks a lot